# sqlite table stores the first record but not after that

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created a database and added it to asset folder. Table name **orders** has three columns id, orderItems and orderDate. In orderItems i'm converting the arraylist to a string and then saving which stores successfully for the first record but when i try to store the second one it shows an error.

Here is the **function** which i'm using to add the records in my **orders Table**.

```
void addOrders(Order ord) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues orderValues = new ContentValues();
    orderValues.put(ORDER_ID, ord.get_orderId());
    orderValues.put(ORDER_ITEMS, ord.get_orderItems()); 
    orderValues.put(ORDER_DATE, ord.get_orderDate()); 

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_ORDERS_NEW, null, orderValues);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

}
```

Here is the **function** which i'm using to convert the **arraylist (selectedProducts)** to string and saving to table.

```
public void saveOrders(){

     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String arrayList = gson.toJson(selectedProducts);

     db.addOrders(new Order(arrayList, formattedDate));

}
```

**DatabaseHandler.class**

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

```
// All Static variables

private static String TAG = DatabaseHandler.class.getName();

// Database Path
 private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.WaqasAsgharBhalli.za_traders/databases/";
  private static String DB_NAME = "myDatabase.sqlite";
  private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null; 
  private final Context myContext;

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;                                   

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS_NEW = "customer";
// Medicine table name
private static final String TABLE_PRODUCT_NEW = "products";
// Medicine table name
private static final String TABLE_USERLOGIN_NEW = "userlogin";
// ORDERS table name
private static final String TABLE_ORDERS_NEW = "orders";                                                 

// Contacts Table Columns name
private static final String CUSTOMER_ID = "id";
private static final String CUSTOMER_CODE = "code";
private static final String CUSTOMER_NAME = "name";
private static final String CUSTOMER_ADDRESS = "address";
private static final String CUSTOMER_LICENCECENO = "licenceNo";

// Product Table Columns name
private static final String PRODUCT_ID = "id";
private static final String PRODUCT_CODE = "pcode";
private static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "pname";
private static final String PRODUCT_PRICE = "price";
private static final String PRODUCT_QUANTITY = "quantity";

// UserLogin Table Columns name
private static final String USERLOGIN_ID = "id";
private static final String USERLOGIN_USERCODE = "usercode";
private static final String USERLOGIN_NAME = "uname";
private static final String USERLOGIN_PASSWORD = "password";

// Order Table Columns name
private static final String ORDER_ID = "id";
private static final String ORDER_ITEMS = "orderItems";
private static final String ORDER_DATE = "orderDate";


// CREATING CUSTOMER CONTACT TABLE
private static final  String CREATE_CONTACTS_CUSTOMER = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS_NEW + "("
        + CUSTOMER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + CUSTOMER_CODE + " TEXT,"
        + CUSTOMER_NAME + " TEXT," + CUSTOMER_LICENCECENO + " TEXT," 
        + CUSTOMER_ADDRESS + " TEXT"+");";

// CREATING PRODUCT TABLE
private static final  String CREATE_CONTACTS_PRODUCTS = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCT_NEW + "("
        + PRODUCT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ PRODUCT_CODE + " TEXT," 
        + PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT,"  + PRODUCT_PRICE + " DOUBLE," 
        + PRODUCT_QUANTITY + " INTEGER" +");";

// CREATING USERLOGIN TABLE
private static final  String CREATE_CONTACTS_USERLOGIN = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERLOGIN_NEW + "("
        + USERLOGIN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + USERLOGIN_USERCODE + " TEXT,"
        + USERLOGIN_NAME + " TEXT,"  + USERLOGIN_PASSWORD + " TEXT"+");";

// CREATING ORDERS TABLE
private static final  String CREATE_CONTACTS_ORDERS = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ORDERS_NEW + "("
        + ORDER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
        + ORDER_ITEMS + " TEXT,"  + ORDER_DATE + " DATETIME"+");                                             

public DatabaseHandler (Context context) throws IOException  {
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
    this.myContext=context;
    boolean dbexist = checkDatabase();
    if(dbexist)
    {
        //System.out.println("Database exists");
        openDatabase(); 
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    createDatabase();
    }

}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */

public void createDatabase() throws IOException{
    boolean dbexist = checkDatabase();
    if(dbexist)
    {
        //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
    }
    else{
        this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
            copyDatabase();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
public boolean checkDatabase() {
    //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    boolean checkdb = false;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        checkdb = dbfile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
        System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
    }

    return checkdb;
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myinput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/com.WaqasAsgharBhalli.za_traders/databases/myDatabase.sqlite");

    // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myoutput.flush();
    myoutput.close();
    myinput.close();

}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLException
{
    //Open the database
    String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDataBase != null){
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS_NEW);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCT_NEW);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERLOGIN_NEW);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDERS_NEW);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

The error which i'm getting whenever i try to enter the second record.

```
07-19 00:43:03.198: I/SQLiteAssetHelper(1741): successfully opened database myDatabase.sqlite
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741): Error inserting id=0 orderItems=[{"_product_name":"BETNESOL TAB","_product_Code":"0343","_price":21.6,"_id":6,"_quantity":29},{"_product_name":"Q.PIN TAB 100MG","_product_Code":"2132","_price":221.0,"_id":10,"_quantity":11}] orderDate=19-Jul-2014
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.WaqasAsgharBhalli.za_traders.DatabaseHandler.addOrders(DatabaseHandler.java:584)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.WaqasAsgharBhalli.za_traders.SelectedMedicineList.saveOrders(SelectedMedicineList.java:139)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.WaqasAsgharBhalli.za_traders.SelectedMedicineList.onOptionsItemSelected(SelectedMedicineList.java:117)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2502)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:950)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:163)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-19 00:43:03.386: E/SQLiteDatabase(1741):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the constraint that failed? My first guess would be that it is a unique constraint on the id. Did the second record you tried to INSERT have the same id as the first one?

Comment: @DavidConrad Exactly the second record shows the same id as the first one. But i,m using id as auto increment

Comment: You have comments "`// UserLogin Name`" and "`// UserLogin Address`" on the `ORDER_ITEMS` and `ORDER_DATE` lines. Uh...?

Comment: @DavidConrad its by mistake there because i use it before for insert table so i just copy it and edit it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly setting the ID in the `ContentValues` you pass to `db.insert` instead of letting the database automatically generate IDs for you. With the ID set to auto increment the database will generate IDs unless you explicitly give an ID, in which case it will try to use the ID you specified.

Remove this line from your code:

`orderValues.put(ORDER_ID, ord.get_orderId());`

Comment: No i,m not .... This is how i,m creating the table.          Create table orders (id integer primary key autoincrement, orderItems text, orderDate text); i don,t think so that i,m setting it explicitly but it shows the id = 0 for the first record as well

Comment: I mean, you're setting it explicitly in the `ContentValues` object you pass to `db.insert`. I'll update my answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Constraint error. That means you have to check the setup of you database.

If you for example try to insert a primary key twice with the same value it will give this error.

Could you post your db helper to see if your input is compliant with your db setup.

Can be unique value, primary key value etc.

Comment: I have added the DatabaseHandler class ... Please have a look at it

Comment: I still think you should check your ID's. You can't insert 0 twice. Next to that I doubt if your string is correct. Your table order only have three fields, but in your log I can read a whole line with productname, price, quantity etc. Try debug it with a string you write out, instead of retrieving it from the Gson class.

Comment: That "whole line" with product name, price, quantity, etc. is the value that is going into one of those three fields. @waqasbhalli345 should probably look into database normalization, third normal form, etc. If you ever need to, say, find all orders with product code 123 or all orders with prices between 100 and 200 dollars, the only way to do it would be to read and return every row and filter them at the application level.

Comment: @DavidConrad yes you right its saving all this in one record. Its basically a order taking app now i need to sync these records to web using web service and don,t need to normalize it because its the demand of the customer. All the records will further manage on web. By the way thanks for your this great help ... I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you set `id` as `autoincrement`, you **can't** specifically set it (to `ord.get_orderId()`, in this case).

You should delete that `orderValues.put(ORDER_ID, ord.get_orderId());` line. Or, create another field in the table for storing that `ord.get_orderId()`.

Comment: Apparently, you **can** specifically set it, you just *shouldn't*.

Comment: @Mike Pascual .... You are right i removed it and its working perfectly now. Thanks a lot my friend :)